# Problem in integrations

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, intuition

We have to find the integration of $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}$

I'm not able to start the following integration, as I try to put $x=\sqrt{2}\tan t $. But from this I got no results.

Can anybody please give me a proper start.

[image]

Comment: Use Latex for your type. You've been on this site for a while, you should know this by now. Also, your problem is missing a parenthesis so it is difficult to determine what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using integration by parts twice:**

\begin{align*}
  I &= \int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}} \,dx \\[4pt]
  &= x\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}-
     \int x \, d \left( \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}} \right) \\[4pt]
  &= x\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}-
     \int \frac{x\left( 1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}} \right)}
               {2\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}} \, dx \\[4pt]
  &= x\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}-
     \int \frac{x\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}}
               {2\sqrt{x^2+2}} \, dx \\[4pt]
  &= x\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}-\frac{1}{2}
     \int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}\, d\left( \sqrt{x^2+2} \right) \\[4pt]
  &= x\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2}}{2} \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}} \\
  &\quad \: +\frac{1}{2}
     \int \sqrt{x^2+2} \, d\left( \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}} \right) \\[4pt]
  &= \left( x-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2}}{2} \right) \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}+
     \frac{1}{4} \int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}} \,dx \\[4pt]
  &= \left( x-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2}}{2} \right) \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}+
     \frac{I}{4}+C' \\[4pt]
  I &= \frac{2}{3} \left( 2x-\sqrt{x^2+2} \right) \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}+C
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Use Euler substitution: $${x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}=t$$
$$dx=\dfrac{t^2+2}{2t^2}$$
The integral becomes:
$$\int\sqrt{t}\times\dfrac{t^2+2}{2t^2}dt=\int\dfrac{\sqrt{t}}{2}+t^{\frac{-3}{2}}dt$$

$$\dfrac{1}{3}\times\dfrac{(t^2-6)}{\sqrt{t}}$$

Comment: How do you get the value of dx

Comment: ${x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}=t \implies x^2+2=(t-x)^2$ Thus: $t^2-2xt+x^2=x^2+2 \implies \dfrac{t^2-2}{2t}=x$ This is very common when using euler substitution. The value of $dx=\dfrac{t^2+2}{2t^2}$